# 403 Forbidden vhost Ubuntu

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

Trying to setup my webserver and allow .htaccess in all www directories. When accessing sub.domain.com on my laptop (with host files adjusted), returns a 403 Forbidden. *"You don't have permission to access / on this server."*

It feels like the .htaccess file is not allowed, and therefore throws the 403. But as per my understanding the settings are correct isn't? Am I overlooking something?

**apache2.conf**

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

**domain.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias sub.domain.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html/support/current
        <Directory "/var/www/domain.com/public_html/support/current">
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias .domain.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html/support/current
        <Directory "/var/www/domain.com/public_html/support/current">
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Is it possible that the user www-data which is the default apache-user has no rights for the folder you specify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `/var/www/domain.com/public_html/support/current` doesn't exist, or its rights are not correct for user Apache runs on. Check the `User` and `Group` settings in the main Apache config to find out what they are.

You might also want to check the error log to get additional clues.